# Updating a column in a table from another table using postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.3

I have table named ´cities´ with 3 columns named:

```
state, name, pop
```

And a table `cities1` with:

```
state, name
```

The columns `state` and `name` are common for both tables. I want the column `pop` alone from cities to be inserted in `cities1` table.
How this can be done using postgreSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to add a column `pop` of specific type to your `cities1` table, and then fill it.

```
ALTER TABLE cities1 ADD COLUMN pop [datatype here]
```

Update `pop` column in table `cities1` with values from `cities` where `state,name` are the common columns.

```
UPDATE cities1
SET pop = cities.pop
FROM cities
WHERE cities1.state = cities.state
    AND cities1.name = cities.name
```